# Contacts created via the APi are not showing in the Xero app

Tags: xero-api

We've setup an "app" using a custom connection, and we're using the xero-ruby gem in a Rails app to interact with Xero.  Using the accounting_api.get_contacts('').contacts method, I can see the contacts in the "Demo" company supplied by Xero.  When I use the accounting_api.create_contacts method I can create contacts, and I get back successful responses with contactIDs, etc.  When I use the accounting_api.get_contacts('').contacts method again, I can see all the Demo contacts, including the new ones I've created.

Trouble is I don't see these new contacts within the Xero app.  If I go to Demo, I see the same contacts being returned by the api, except for the new ones I've created.  Same with invoices... I can create them via the API but I don't see them in the Xero app.  I've had our accountant look, and he should have full authority to everything, and he doesn't see them either.  Any ideas on what could be going wrong?

Comment: I think I'm connected to the wrong "Demo" company.  I'm looking into it.

Comment: Yeah, that was it... seems we have two environments, both with "Demo".  I'll leave this Q&A here in case someone else is as clueless as me :)

Comment: Good man Steve.  Thanks for following up that you've resolved it.

When in doubt, pull the Organisations endpoint to determine which org you're making request to.  You can also use the connections endpoints to determine which access tokens you have, and for which tenants (orgs).